# Ambiguity in XCode's Memory Leak Instrument TimeLine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

In the following image (taken from Memory Leaks Instrument in Xcode), you will notice a memory leak (the one with green border) in the timeline, how do i know which leaked object(s) that caused this red vertical line (the leak) ? if it's not possible to determine which object is the responsible for the leak, then what's the benefit of displaying these red vertical lines in the timeline ?

thank you so much in advance.

the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The red vertical lines signify increases in leaks.  They are not in real time (therefore they can't be one-vs-one).  See the "Snapshot Interval" section on the left?  That's how often Instruments will look for new leaks.  If it finds some, it will put a red bar in your timeline.  To figure out which ones are new, check before and after on the timeline.